# SQL server RDS with elasticccahe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elasticache

Can RDS SQL Server be integrated with Elasticache. Can SQL server read replica be created?

Comment: Huh?! - please elaborate the use case in more detail.

Comment: Also, this seems like two separate questions.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask] and [mcve]. And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 0):

1) "Can RDS SQL Server be integrated with Elasticache"?

No, but you could use ElasticCache in the same AWS account as an RDS SQL server and potentially use them in the same programs.  But the databases they used would be separate and distinct

2) "Can SQL Read Replica be created"?
Yes, this is a standard feature of RDS.  See https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/